# Segfault: 11 when running tests (XCode 8, Swift 2.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Since moving my mixed Swift and Objective-c project to XCode 8 with Swift 2.3, I have been getting a "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11" error every time I run my tests after making a change in any of the test files.

When I click on the error for more information I see:

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1: 
#import "Headers/Utilities.h"
    ^
/Users/.../Utilities.framework/Headers/Utilities.h:18:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Utilities'
#import <Utilities/NSString+Utilities.h>
^
```

And basically just a bunch of similar errors following that ending in:

```
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Utilities'
```

Utilities in this case is a framework that I made. All of the headers in the Utilities.h file are imported with angle brackets and the headers are marked as public.

After it segfaults, it will run properly until I make a change to the test file. It only has this issue when testing, not when building or running.

Other things I've tried:

- Changing the framework and tests to allow non modular includes
- Enabling/disabling bitcode

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue in sift2.3 due to memory allocation.

if you are returning any object or method from utility try to avoid keep the method inside same class, also clean code and clear derivedata and run

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean about keeping the method inside the same class. Many attempts at cleaning and deleting derived data have had no impact on this issue.